# Java - Reading RadioButton default value

Tags: java, itext

I create a pdf form with iText java containing a radio group (PdfFormField.createRadioButton) with a default button selected (checked).  I open the pdf (new PdfReader) and examine the fields. The radiobutton field value is empty.  I open the pdf with acrobat, click the already checked radiobutton and save the pdf.  When I reopen the pdf to examine the field values, the radiobutton value is now present.  What am I leaving out when I create the original pdf?  Thanks, Kenneth

Comment: More info is needed to answer this question. For instance: please share a link to the PDF you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Added a call to "radio_field_name.setValueAsName("SomeRadioValue");".  Now I can retrieve default value from the PDF.  Thanks